# View output in Aws Lambda basic function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

i'm trying to invode aws lambda function using Java in my Eclipse, if i pass input as any string, the function is calling successfully but, i'm seeing null as the output, but i'm expecing the input text itself as output.

Here is my code

```
    package simpledynamodb;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {

         context.getLogger().log("Input is working");

         context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return null;
    }

}
```

The output looks like

```
    Uploading function code to dynamodbmaven...
Upload success. Function ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:169456523019:function:dynamodbmaven
Invoking function...
==================== FUNCTION OUTPUT ====================
null
```

In my code i'm passing "Hello world" as input text, i'm suppose to see the passed string instead i'm getting null.

My handler class, everything seems to be fine. Here is the pic of my lambda configuration

[image]

Can you tell me where i'm wrong in this?.

Answer (score 1):

I'm super late here but the reason you aren't seeing the output is because you are looking at the output in Eclipse - which only returns the result of your function invocation. 
You should look at the Cloudwatch Logs for the Lambda to get the logs of the run.

Answer (score 0):

It's printing `null` because that's what the function is returning.

I assume when you say you should be getting the input text as output, what you really mean is that you should be seeing in the input string in the logs. I'm guessing you have the logging configured such that those logs aren't printing. To get past the logging configuration issues just to see what your input string is, you might try using `System.out` instead of `context.getLogger().log`